# Vague build error message in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to build a package under Anaconda using the `conda` utility, but I get an error message that is too vague to be actionable:

```
BUILD END: pymc-2.3.2-np17py27_0
TEST START: pymc-2.3.2-np17py27_0
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications
Hint: pymc 2.3.2 np17py27_0 has a conflict with the remaining packages
```

How are we to know which packages it is conflicting with? I'm not even sure what "remaining packages" refers to, as I am building a single package, so there are no remaining packages as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, the error message is vague.  To debug this it would be useful to know which conda-recipe is being used, and also which version of conda.  Using conda 3.0.5, I am able to build the pymc recipe in https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes without any problems.  Thanks.

Comment: That's because I just merged a pull request that removes pydot as a dependency.